# Unable to parse JSON Data with a list of dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I want to parse JSON Data into C#

The data is:

```
"{\"data\":

{\"6\":{\"id\":\"6\",\"reward_definition_id\":12,\"person_id\":164305,\"issue_date\":\"2015-10-08\",\"expiry_date\":\"2015-11-08\",\"amount_initial\":20,\"amount_remaining\":0,\"

_member_details\":{\"id\":\"164305\",\"first_name\":\"test\",\"last_name\":\"one\",\"email\":\"testing1@example.com\",\"_email_trigger\":\"Y\",\"_email_bounced\":\"N\",\"_email_promo\":\"Y\",\"_app_notify\":\"Y\",\"_sms_status\":\"Y\",\"active\":\"Y\"},

\"_store_details\":null,\"_staff_details\":null,\"_product_details\":null},

\"5\":{\"id\":\"5\",\"reward_definition_id\":12,\"person_id\":164305,\"issue_date\":\"2015-10-08\",\"expiry_date\":\"2015-11-08\",\"amount_initial\":20,\"amount_remaining\":20,\"

_member_details\":{\"id\":\"164305\",\"first_name\":\"test\",\"last_name\":\"one\",\"email\":\"testing1@example.com\",\"_email_trigger\":\"Y\",\"_email_bounced\":\"N\",\"_email_promo\":\"Y\",\"_app_notify\":\"Y\",\"_sms_status\":\"Y\",\"active\":\"Y\"},

\"_store_details\":null,\"_staff_details\":null,\"_product_details\":null}

}}"
```

How to create a Class with Dictionary of lists of this data and deserialize it into C# class.  I am trying to use the following classes to store this json data, the classes are

```
public class JsonRewardResponse
{    
    public Dictionary<int, JsonRewardDetails> mydictionary { get; set; }
}

public class JsonRewardDetails
{    
    public string Id;
    public int reward_definition_id;
    public int person_id;
    public string issue_date;
    public string expiry_date;
    public int amount_initial;
    public int amount_remaining;
    public JsonMemberDetails member;`enter code here`
    public int _store_details;
    public int _staff_details;
    public int product_details;
}

public class JsonMemberDetails
{
    public string Id;
    public string first_name;
    public string last_name;
    public string email;
    public string _email_trigger;
    public string _email_bounced;
    public string _email_promo;
    public string _app_notify;
    public string _sms_status;
    public string active;
}
```

Please help Thanks in Advance.

Bharath AK

Comment: What serializer are you using?  Json.NET?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what serializer you are using, so the advice I am giving is relevant for for all JSON serializers.

You have a few problems here:

1. The name of the property `mydictionary` should be `data`, as that's what is in the JSON.
2. `product_details` should be renamed to `_product_details`.
3. `_store_details`, `_staff_details` and `_product_details` are declared to be `int`, however they appear as `null` in the JSON.  Thus they need to be some sort of nullable type in c#, for instance `int?` or `string`.  (The fact that these are null in the JSON suggests, but does not prove, that they are not integer types when non-null.)
4. `member` should be renamed to `_member_details`.

Thus:

```
public class JsonRewardResponse
{
    public Dictionary<int, JsonRewardDetails> data { get; set; }
}

public class JsonRewardDetails
{
    public string Id;
    public int reward_definition_id;
    public int person_id;
    public string issue_date;
    public string expiry_date;
    public int amount_initial;
    public int amount_remaining;
    public JsonMemberDetails member;
    public int? _store_details;
    public int? _staff_details;
    public int? _product_details;
}

public class JsonMemberDetails
{
    public string Id;
    public string first_name;
    public string last_name;
    public string email;
    public string _email_trigger;
    public string _email_bounced;
    public string _email_promo;
    public string _app_notify;
    public string _sms_status;
    public string active;
}
```

With these fixes, using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), you can do:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonRewardResponse>(json);
```

(You might have additional issues with other serializers.)

Comment: Thanks dbc, It is now working fine and resolved.  Thanks for your help.  The problem was  I was under assumption, dictionary is a single item not iterative item, just like a single key value pair, that is where I was going wrong. I am using Newtonsoft JSON, Now I had included JsonProperty for child dictionaries now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to deserialize JSON, I either use the dynamic type in c# or if I want todo what you are doing I feed the json into the web site:

http://json2csharp.com/

I've never had an issue with that.

Comment: Hi Peter,  Thanks for your reply,  I was under assumption, dictionary is a single item not iterative item, just like a single key value pair, that is where I was going  wrong.  I am using Newtonsoft JSON, I had included JsonProperty for child dictionaries now it is working fine.  Thanks for your reply.